# Fixed size Image uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want upload image with fixed size in codeigniter.But my code is not working.Anyone please help me for doing this..My code is

```
public function createevent() {

            if ($this->input->post('submit')) {

                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
                $config['max_width'] = '366';       
                $config['max_height'] = '269';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    //    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $data = $this->upload->data();
                    $logo = $data['file_name'];  
          $fileInfo = getimagesize($data);

    if( $fileInfo['width'] == 366 && $fileInfo['height'] == 269 ) {
    //          if(($fileInfo[0] == 366) && ($fileInfo[1] == 269 )){
    //            if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {                         


                        $this->event_model->createevent( $logo);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Event Created');

              }  else {
    //                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Please upload image within the size limit');
                        redirect('event/events');
                }
                }
            }
```

Comment: whats the error please check error in var/log/apache2/error.log also add what you are getting in browser by pressing f12

Comment: Why don't you just let them upload whatever and resize it before doing the upload?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `$fileInfo['image_width']` & `$fileInfo['image_height']` instead of

`$fileInfo['width']` & `$fileInfo['height']`

This will work. :)